# Java failing to connect to a MariaDB database on localhost

Tags: java, database, jdbc, mariadb

I'm trying to connect to my MariaDB database which is on localhost (using xampp). The first time I connect, the connection is established and I managed to create a table with the two fields "username" "password". Thereafter, when I try to do anything else, the Connection turns null and I cannot insert or execute any queries.

```
import java.sql.*;

class MyDatabase {
    private Connection conn;
    private PreparedStatement psAddPerson;


    MyDatabase(String host, String user, String password) throws Exception {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb:" + host,
                user, password);
        psAddPerson = null;
    }

    public void addPerson(String username, String password) {
        try{
            if( psAddPerson == null ){
                String sqlAddPerson = "insert into users (usern, pass) values (?,?)";
                psAddPerson = conn.prepareStatement(sqlAddPerson);
            }
            psAddPerson.setString(1, username);
            psAddPerson.setString(2, password);
            psAddPerson.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't create add person");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = "//localhost:3306/test";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "";
        MyDatabase newDb = null;
        try {
            newDb = new MyDatabase(host, user, pass);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String username = "admin";
        String password = "password";
        if (newDb != null) {
            newDb.addPerson(username, password);
        }
    }
}
```

This code produces a NullPointerException when trying to execute following code:

```
psAddPerson = conn.prepareStatement(sqlAddPerson);
```

I want to be able to execute queries to my localhost database.

Picture from phpMyAdmin of server type:
[image: Picture of server type]

Thanks

Comment: @YCF_L Done, but that doesn't change much..

Comment: You're creating an instance of connection within the constructor, you need to initialize the instance variable `conn`

Comment: Ahh ok thanks! @EleazarEnrique

Comment: Of course, it matters, the instance variable is always null because you're instantiating a local variable within the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

`Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb:" + host, user, password);`

by this:

`conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb:" + host, user, password);`

This way you're instantiating the instance variable rather than a local variable within the constructor.

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Thank you :) You were faster than the other guy, so will accept yours as the answer

Comment: Good! :-) Happy coding time!

Answer (score 1):

The fix is easy change:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb:" + host,
            user, password);
```

to:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb:" + host,
            user, password);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tweak it a little bit and change this :**

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb:" + host, user, password);
```

**to this:**

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb:" + host, user, password);
```